# DoesNotReturnAttribute doesn't mark a code after a call as unreachable

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I'm reading the documentation and write some test code to examine new features. For DoesNotReturn attribute [it says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#verify-unreachable-code):

> The compiler marks any code after a call to that method as unreachable, until an appropriate catch clause is encountered.

So I wrote the following code to test it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        var resMsg = SomeMethod();
        Console.WriteLine($"resMsg: {resMsg}");
    }

    [DoesNotReturn]
    static string SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception("Some test exception");
    }
}
```

I expected from the compiler a warning like "Unreachable code detected" on the next line after `SomeMethod()` call but there is not any warnings. Why?

**Edited:**

- The project uses C# 8.0
- Nullable context is enabled

Here is the whole *.csproj file content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.0-rc0001"/>
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing" Version="1.0.0-beta0007"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I believe the attribute is only related to NRT analysis, not *general* code reachability.

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please tell what NRT analysis means? I tried to google this term but found nothing bound with programming

Comment: Nullable Reference Type analysis. (As in, it's only about the handling of C# 8 nullable reference types.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, to be honest, I have no idea how this attribute is related to Nullable Reference Type analysis. How is it used and how can I use it?

Comment: The whole page you linked to is about Nullable Reference Type analysis. The title is "Reserved attributes contribute to the compiler's null state static analysis". If you don't feel you *need* to use these, you probably don't need to.

Comment: `<Nullable>annotations</Nullable>` or `#nullable enable annotations` may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

> Upgrading the language version selects C# 8.0, but does not enable the nullable annotation context or the nullable warning context. Rebuild the project to ensure that it builds without warnings.

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/upgrade-to-nullable-references)

As mentioned in the 2nd paragraph there:

> All the examples assume C# 8.0 or newer, and the code is in a nullable context.

So you need to check your .csproj file and make sure the Nullable context is enabled.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the project already points to C# 8.0 and nullable context is enabled. I've just edited my post and added these details.

Answer (score 0):

Test without DoesNotReturn. Does compiler give you a warning? What I have tested, no. See below.

This one generates warning

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");

        throw new Exception("Some test exception");

        var resMsg = SomeMethod();
        Console.WriteLine($"resMsg: {resMsg}");
    }

    static string SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception("Some test exception");
    }
}
```

And this one do not

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");

        //throw new Exception("Some test exception");

        var resMsg = SomeMethod();
        Console.WriteLine($"resMsg: {resMsg}");
    }

    static string SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new Exception("Some test exception");
    }
}
```